# HTML Table search single cell

Tags: javascript, html, search, html-table

I have been looking for a code to search a table and display a single cell. Kept trying to make my own and eventually found one that works perfectly except for one thing. When the search bar is emptied, it displays the first cell, I don't know how to make it so it goes back to displaying the whole table.

Here's the code and any help is really appreciated.

```js
    var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
    var search = document.getElementById("myInput");

    search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
            if (cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
                cells.forEach(function(element) {
                    element.style.display = "none";
                });
                cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
                break;
            } else {
                cells.forEach(function(element) {
                    if (cells[i] !== element) {
                        element.style.display = "table-cell";
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>asd</td>
        <td>dsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>321</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>412</td>
        <td>124</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here's the code in action and you can see what my problem is: https://jsfiddle.net/y1wof1go/

Comment: Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/wAxNu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When nothing is entered in input box (length is zero or empty string) you need to make all cells in your table visible again.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1wof1go/13/).

and update function:

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
var search = document.getElementById("myInput");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    if (search.value.length > 0 && search.value != '') {
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
            if (cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
                cells.forEach(function(element) {
                    element.style.display = "none";
                });
                cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
                break;
            } else {
                cells.forEach(function(element) {
                    if (cells[i] !== element) {
                        element.style.display = "table-cell";
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        cells.forEach(function(element) {
            if (cells[i] !== element) {
                element.style.display = "table-cell";
            }
        });

    }
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>asd</td>
        <td>dsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>321</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>412</td>
        <td>124</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

So to make sure the table returns to its default state when the search is empty add an if statement checking if the search bar is empty. If the bar is empty, then set all of the table elements back to showing with the normal `table-cell` style.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
var search = document.getElementById("myInput");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
    if (cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
      cells.forEach(function(element) {
        element.style.display = "none";
      });
      cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
      break;
    } else {
      cells.forEach(function(element) {
        if (cells[i] !== element) {
          element.style.display = "table-cell";
        }
      });
    }
  }
  if (search.value == "") {
    cells.forEach(function(element) {
      if (cells[i] !== element) {
        element.style.display = "table-cell";
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<table id="myTable">

  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>dsa</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>321</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>412</td>
    <td>124</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to reset all items on any platform, it is often best to perform a blanket reset to the original state:

```
search.addEventListener('keyup', function()
{
    if (search.value.length > 0 && search.value != '')
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i)
        {
            if(cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.value.toLowerCase()) === 0)
            {
                cells.forEach(function(element)
                {
                    element.style.display = 'none';
                });
                cells[i].style.display = 'table-cell';
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cells.forEach(function(element)
                {
                    if (cells[i] !== element)
                    {
                        element.style.display = 'table-cell';
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cells.forEach(function(element)
        {
            if (cells[i] !== element)
            {
                element.style.display = 'table-cell';
            }
        });
}
```